# Example of where Class Echo abuts class Golf

Tags: aeronautical-charts

Aeronautical Chart Users' Guide shows an example of a fuzzy magenta line bordering with class Golf airspace. I tried to look but couldn't find any examples on the charts. If you have seen it, please point me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

[image: excerpt from Aeronautical Chart Users' Guide]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example in Alaska: the [Cape Lisburne LRRS Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Lisburne_LRRS_Airport).

As a bonus, note the rare NDB-DME and LF/MF airway (Blue 2)!

[image: Detail from the Cape Lisburne VFR Sectional Chart showing the Cape Lisburne (Alaska) LRRS Airport and its associated E-from-700' airspace, and neighboring E-from-14500' airspace to the west and northwest.]

Comment: You also got the pretty uncommon sea lion protection area marker.